# Parse and count total sum of numbers - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, google-apps-script, sum

I am exporting items to Google sheet. Item values include dot instead of comma, so I probably need to parse them first before I can count the total sum? What would be the best way to do this using Google Apps Script? I need to automate this process so I cannot use Google Sheets built in functions.

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if the values are imported as string instead of numbers.  Check if there are quotation marks around the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myfunk1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Your sheet name');
  const sum = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow() -2,1).getDisplayValues().reduce((a,c)=>{ a+=parseFloat(c);return a;},0);
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().forEach((r,i) => {if(r[0]=='sum')sh.getRange(i + 2,2).setValue(Number(sum).toFixed(2))});
}
```

Ouput:

| Item | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 57.9 |
| 2 | 111.9 |
| 3 | 39.9 |
| sum | 209.7 |